# Upgrade by define upgrade function of bank account that refers to another class (python)

Tags: python, function, class, instance, bank

I have a question where I am stuck. I have to create a function that is called for example improve_acc which receives two arguments from an instance of another class called "bankacc" and a function proof_wealth.

If the first argument is not an instance of "bankacc" class, it must print "sorry, this is not a bank account". If the proof_wealth is less than 1000, it should print:"you cannot receive this upgrade"

If it passes the two conditions it should create a new bank account with the name and balance from instance of "bankcc_prime" and return this new instance.

My code so far:

I wrote a first code:

```
class BankAcc(): 

    def __init__(self, owner, balance = 0):
    ...

class BankAccountPrime():
    def __init__(self,proof_wealth, owner, balance)
```

and then the last code:

```
def upgrade_account(self, BankAcc, proof_wealth):
    self.BankAccount = BankAcc
    self.proof_wealth = proof_wealth

        for instance in BankAcc:
            if instance in BankAcc and proof_wealth > 1000:
                return BankAccountPrime
            elif instance not in BankAccc:
                print('Sorry, this is not a Bank Account.')
            else: 
                proof_wealth < 1000
                print("You cannot receive this upgrade")
```

I would appreciate your help! Thanks

Comment: This sounds and smells like a school assignment? The indentation of the code is a bit off so tried to fix it, correct me if I'm wrong :) There's a lot of unclear information here. For instance, what's `proof_wealth`, how have you tried to check if the first argument is a `instance` of something? And when you say "first argument", to which function/class are you referring to. I would recommend trying to frame the question a bit more clear, and add the missing details, would help in helping you.

Comment: Hey: yes I didnt want to stress it too much. But there are these exercises beforehand: 1.  Create a BankAccount class.
    It must have two attributes:
        - owner, balance
    This class should have three methods:
        - deposit
        - withdraw
        - show_balance 
Second: Create a BankAccountPrime class. It must have all the attributes and 
     methods as the class BankAccount and more. 
     
     a)
     The attributes must be: 
        - owner
        - balance
        - proof_wealth
        - credit

Comment: So, as a general rule. Getting help with school assignments are not really what we're here for. It's more if you're stuck on an actual problem/error. Lets say you're getting errors using `isinstance`. I would ask your teacher for help, and there's a very important reason to do so. he or she will teach you how to think, not just how to solve it. And understanding how to think and the concepts is way more important than just getting the answer to your problem. So ask your teacher to explain the concepts if you feel you're stuck, as these are quite trivial tasks :)

Comment: Sure, I dont want the code but I don't understand for example what it means to create function that receives two arguments, an instance of bankaccount and proof_wealth? should I write: def function(BankAccount, proof_wealth)??

Comment: And this is why it's extremely important that your teacher convey these concepts. what a function is should be clear as glass to you. What parameters to a function is - should also be second nature. An instance is also a very fundamental concept *(since you're obviously studying object oriented programming, which is cool, congrats on passing basic courses)* at this level, understand them before trying to solve this. Spoiler: Currently, you don't have `bankaccount` or `proof_wealth` even defined anywhere. You have it written and you're trying to **use** it, but you haven't **defined** it :)

Comment: And before this question gets closed, and in case your teacher won't help you. Here's the basic concepts you need to know: https://gist.github.com/Torxed/4dc6e164dd14b26a88ae8e95b5621ef8 and if those are unclear, experiment with them and really understand them. That should be all you need to know (together with Ehtesham's answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Please use `isinstance`

```
   isinstance(bank_account, BankAcc)
```

Comment: Hey, where in the code should i use isinstance? thanks